# importing pandas module, Attribute error with "pickle" module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pickle, attributeerror

My code: `import pandas`

Error showing:

```
  File "D:/.../pandas_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 60, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 104, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 151, in <module>
    class NDFrame(PandasObject, SelectionMixin, indexing.IndexingMixin):
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2670, in NDFrame
    protocol: int = pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL,
AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute 'HIGHEST_PROTOCOL'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I worked with pandas module last week with the same PC there was no problem. I faced this error today. Don't know much about pickle module. 
I've reinstalled pandas module nothing changed.

Python version: 3.7.6
Windows 10

Comment: What version of `pandas`? `import pandas; pandas.__version__`

Comment: @jorijnsmit version is 1.0.2